# How to export KML file without having layer name in front of field name in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, line, kml, google-earth

I output the KML file from shape file (line). It's include the description of the distance of line. When I output to KML, it showed the layer name in front of Field name (e.g- 11:Descriptio - 648.38 ==> in this example, "11" is layer name which was given before output, "Descriptio" is field name and "648.38" is the value of Descriptio field.

[image]